# Multiple definition of in C

Tags: c, eclipse

I have a project written in C consisting of FIFO.h, FIFO.c, task.h, task.c and main.c (it's a basic queue).
When I compile my main.c using gcc under Windows it compiles and works just fine. However when I try to compile the exact same code in Eclipse, I get the following error for every function:

One example is:

```
In function `queue_new':
FIFO\Debug/../src/QueueFIFO.c:20: multiple definition of `queue_new'
src\main.o:FIFO\Debug/../src/QueueFIFO.c:20: first defined here
src\FIFO.o:
```

I honestly have no idea what additional information you guys could use so just tell me what to do.

main.c includes:

```
#include "FIFO.h"
#include "FIFO.c"
#include "task.h"
```

QueueFIFO.c:

```
#include "task.h"
```

FIFO.c:

```
#include "task.h"
#include "QueueFIFO.c"
```

task.c:

```
#include "task.h"
```

Comment: You will need to show us the lines in `FIFO\Debug/../src/QueueFIFO.c` and `src\main.c`

Comment: Not so much the actual code, but the preprocessor lines (every line starting with `#`) and function declarations.  The function bodies probably aren't a factor here.

Comment: Why are you including `.c` files in your header files?

Comment: Don't include the `.c` files: just the `.h` files.

Comment: What @hmjd said. Also, if your .h files aren't properly guarded, you'll probably run into problems.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Answer (score 1):

You are getting multiple definition errors because you are including your `.c` files in your `.c` files.  It's the linker's job to make sure they come together.  Good practice is to only include `.h` files in your `.c` files, and make sure the `.h` files don't include function definitions (only function prototypes).

By `#include`ing your `.c` files, you are defining the functions at least twice: once when `FIFO.c` is compiled, and again when `main.c` (which `#include`s `FIFO.c`, copying it verbatim into the text before compilation) is compiled.  When it comes to link time, the linker sees e.g. `queue_new()` defined in both `FIFO.o` and `main.o` and barfs on the multiple definition of all the functions in `FIFO.c`.

In addition, as others mentioned, make sure you "guard" your header files to make sure they don't create circular `#include` dependencies.  You can do that with `#ifndef` and `#define` as follows:

```
/* foo.h */

#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "bar.h"
#include "baz.h"

/* header file contents go here */

#endif /* FOO_H */
```

This has the effect of only executing the contents of the file once, since FOO_H will be defined if it is included a second time, and the entirety of the file will be skipped over.